# jquery css vertical drop-down menu with sub-levels from unordered list

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

i want to transform an unordered list into a vertical dropdown menu like in this example: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Vertical-Responsive-Multi-level-Nav-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3/

Is there a easy way of doing this? i tried the example above but is not working,

This is my structure :

```
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>text</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>text</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div>text</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>text</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>text</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div>text</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>text</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>text</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>text</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: ...and you haven't actually provided an example.

Comment: added now the example url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example:
http://jsfiddle.net/s6jdem6L/

Remove all of the default list styling using

```
list-style:none;
```

Then set each `li` to `position:relative`. Then set the child `ul` to `display:absolute`. This will make it so using `top`, and `left` will absolutely position the element relative to the `li` (because it has `position:relative`). Then put it where you want. You can then use `overflow:hidden` and `max-width` to hide the child `ul`. (there are many other ways to do this too). Then use the `:hover` pseudo selector to expand the child `ul` on hover of the parent `li`.